# div box list generating SQL query, needs rearranging

Tags: mysql, sql

So I am working on a logging system, that writes to a database. I am calling entries from a database to be written to this page:

www.benjaminpotter.org/elog/logbook.php

Now all is fine at the moment but the problem is that the nature of the SQL query I used to get these divs, and then the lists between them has set it so that I am looking at the earliest entry first.

For example, press the `<` button twice and you can see the most recent entry.

So I was wondering how I could start viewing them with the most recent entry first?

Here is the current sql I use:

```
SELECT * FROM logbook WHERE logId > '" . $lower . "' AND logId <= '" . $count . "' ORDER BY date DESC
```

Where "lower" is altered depending on the div being generated, and count represents the first id being placed in this div.

Hope that makes sense!

Comment: do you use some CREATION_DATE fields in you Log table? i think, it's most popular way of getting recent entries.

Comment: I tried several browser to press your buttons but nothing seems to happen in: Opera 11, Firefox 5, IE 9.

Comment: anyway - I do have a date yes - its known as date within the table. that is the date created.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the last id (I'll assume $lower is the last id) on the form, simply select a page full of records that are bigger then the last id.

```
SELECT * FROM logbook 
WHERE logId > '" . $lower . "' 
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT 10
```